# How to bind a LIKE wildcard in SQLite3

Tags: sql, c, sqlite

I'd like to run the SQL query: `SELECT COUNT(id) AS nbr FROM user WHERE name LIKE '%John%'`, and get the number of records matched by the keyword `John`.

So I've written the following code :

```
unsigned int nbr;
char *sql, *like;
sqlite3 *db;
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

/* Database connection etc. */

like = _make_string("%%%s%%", keyword); /* keyword: John */
printf("Like clause: %s\n", like);

sql = _make_string("SELECT COUNT(id) AS nbr FROM user WHERE name LIKE ?");
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL);
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, like, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);

if (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_ROW) {
    /* error, SQL execution failed */
}
nbr = sqlite3_column_int64(stmt, 1);
printf("Number of record: %u\n", nbr);

/* Free strings, finalize statement, disconnect db etc. */
```

For reason of simplicity, some return value tests are ignored in the snippet. `_make_string(const char *fmt, ...)` is a `printf`-like function which can form strings, and it did return `%John%` to me.

However, my code always returns 0 record. I have tried the SQL in `sqlite3` command line shell, but it has found 2 records.

Any idea please ?

---

I've hard coded the LIKE clause and removed the `sqlite3_bind_text` function, and it doesn't change the result.

```
sql = _make_string("SELECT COUNT(id) AS nbr FROM client WHERE name LIKE '%John%'");
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL);
if (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_ROW) {
    /* error */
}
nbr = sqlite3_column_int64(stmt, 1);
printf("Number of record: %u\n", nbr);
```

The program always returns 0 records.

Comment: After registered a tracing function via `sqlite3_trace()`, it turns out that the real SQL executed is still `SELECT COUNT(id) AS nbr FROM user WHERE name LIKE ?', which means the binding didn't work.

Comment: The trace does not show parameter values.

Comment: Does the same code work if you change it to hardcode the string in the query?

Comment: @CL. I've changed the code, but it doesn't change the result. See the update of my post.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've found the answer in the mailing list archive of SQLite [Why bind indexes start from 1 and column indexes start from 0?](http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users%40mailinglists.sqlite.org/msg00289.html)

In fact, the bind index starts from 1, but the column index starts from 0. So the code should be modified as the following

```
nbr = sqlite3_column_int64(stmt, 0);
printf("Number of record: %u.\n", nbr);
```

Now the program returns 2 (records) !